# How many records i can store in coredata

Tags: ios, ipad, sqlite, core-data

First time I make a network hit to (sql)sever to get the table data having 14 fields with image blob mostly. It has above **2 hundred thousand** of records in table.

1. Can we store the 2 hundred thousand records in local database of device using core data.
2. Best way to place images in local file / DB. (or) we can  using remote images loading.
3. Should work offline

Please suggest the best way of possible to fill this above requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Storing 200k records in core data is not a problem in itself as long as you do the initial importing of those records correctly. Make sure you implement you update-or-insert properly otherwise your users will have to wait proportional to N^2. Apple suggests a nice implementation for this: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/articles/cdimporting.html

Then once you have the local data, you probably need to fine tune the batch size of your fetch requests, but that's a good idea to do, even if you don't have 200k records.

As for the images, never ever store them in Core Data as binary blobs. Always store them as normal files on disk and store their path in Core Data to access them later on.